# Golf 3 1992 Model

Tags: vw, sparkplugs

Good day,

Please assist with my car, when driving gear 1 and 2 does not have power. I have change the plucks and the ring gears two months ago and it was fine. Now gear 1 and 2 does not have power again, what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Our 1997 Golf 3 exhibited very poor running and lack of power.  Changing the plugs temporarily fixed the running but then poor running returned.  We tracked this back to the rotor arm which had become brittle and actually broke off in my hand.  A few months later still, poor running returned and this was rectified by replacing the HT (ignition) leads.

Assuming that the problem was the same as ours. If you replace the rotor arm, distributor cap and ignition leads this should solve the issue.  These cars can have problems with their coil packs but typically this stops the car from running at all.